# Can't find point/polygon intersect using QGIS (Windows only)

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, intersection

Below I describe the method I am using.

I have two machines:

1. ubuntu linux, qgis 1.4 - intersection works
2. WIN xp, qgis 1.8 - intersection does not work

Hopefully, someone will find what I am doing wrong I uploaded [this screencast](http://youtu.be/79qYhQGVRE4) showing my problem. The error massage:

```
"Feature geometry error: One or more output features ignored due to invalid geometry.
Some output geometries may be missing or invalid."
```

I also tried some other tweaks:

1. buffering the points layer so I will be doing polygon/polygon intersect - didn't work
2. saving both layers while specifying the same CRS - didn't work

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you really using the same datasets on ubuntu and windows?

Comment: definately, rechecked it twice. it also happens when i create new layers

Comment: can you describe how you intersected both shapes?

Comment: The GDAL version changed between 1.4 and 1.8. Maybe the new one has issues with the datasets.

Comment: Are you using exactly the same files? Do they have any spaces or unusual characters in the Windows directory? Try running the operation with the point and polygons in a C:\workspace\ directory or similar in the root.

Comment: by the way, i did try intersecting in c:\workplace and since i did it once on datasets created just to check it i don't think its a characters problem.

Comment: Could you share the files you're working with?